# TypeError: Unable to modify PDF file, make sure that output file target is available and that it is not protected

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, hummus.js

I'm trying to fill pdf form using [HummusJS](https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS) but it throws me an error `TypeError: Unable to modify PDF file, make sure that output file target is available and that it is not protected` while running pdf generation in AWS lambda function but its working fine on my local machine and log aren't generated. Is there any debugging option available??. I wasted 3 days for solving this issue.

Any help will highly be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try using Lambda Local , it might help u to debug ur issue locally https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-local

Comment: Thanks, Nishant, I'm just looking into it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that, There is some issue in the output file path. It's not able to store the generated pdf file.

Comment: Just from the error this looks to me as if you don't have the permission to store the generated pdf

Comment: in my case my output file path was incorrect, thanks @Sagar

Answer (score -1):

I experienced this issue when the PDF file I was reading had a size of 0. Somewhere during my tests I suspect that the PDF I was working with got overwritten with empty data and it turns out that this is what was creating the permission error.

I was working from [this](https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJSSamples/blob/master/filling-form-values/main.js) sample.